# How to show/hide text by clicking on image "Show" turning it to image "Hide"

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I have the following Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function divToHide(q) {

   var div = document.getElementById(q);

   if (div.style.display == "block") 
   {
       div.style.display = "none"; '<img src="images/showanswer.gif"     border="0" alt="Show Answer">'
   } 
   else 
   {
       div.style.display = "block"; '<img src="images/hideanswer.gif" border="0" alt="Hide Answer">'
    }
}
</script>
```

In the body of HTML code, I have:

```
<a href="javascript:divToHide('q1');">
<img src="images/showanswer.gif" border="0" alt="Show Answer"></a>
<div id="q1" style="display: none">
```

When I click on showanswer, it does show the answer, but the image does not change to hideanswer.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the `src` of the image and not changing the image completely, by the way wrinting :

```
'<img src="images/showanswer.gif"     border="0" alt="Show Answer">'
```

Will not do anything here, you should refer the image and change it's `src` and `alt` attributes acordingly.

This is how you should do it:

```js
function divToHide(id, img) {
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  console.log(img);
  if (div.style.display === "none") {

    div.style.display = "block";
    img.src = "images/hideanswer.gif";
    img.alt = "Hide Answer";
  } else if (div.style.display === "block") {

    div.style.display = "none";
    img.src = "images/showanswer.gif";
    img.alt = "Show Answer";
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="images/showanswer.gif" border="0" id="img1" onclick="divToHide('q1', this);" alt="Show Answer">
<div id="q1" style="display: none">Answer to Question 1</div>



<img src="images/showanswer.gif" border="0" id="img2" onclick="divToHide('q2', this);" alt="Show Answer">

<div id="q2" style="display: none">Answer to Question 2</div>


<img src="images/showanswer.gif" border="0" id="img3" onclick="divToHide('q3', this);" alt="Show Answer">

<div id="q3" style="display: none">Answer to Question 3</div>
```

You can even do better, as the image is unchanged you can get rid of the link `<a>` and simply call the functon on the click event of the image:

```
<img src="images/showanswer.gif" onclick="divToHide('q1');" border="0" id="img" alt="Show Answer">
<div id="q1" style="display: none">Just a test </div>
```

**EDIT**

I edited the function so we can pass the clicked image and the id of the div to show/hide onclick of the image like this `onclick="divToHide('q2', this);"` , so it fits your need.

Comment: I want more items to show/hide on the same page. I am successful in using different id for each item, but the same image for showanswer and hideanswer for each item also should change from showanswer to hidenswer when different items are clicked. This script is not doing that.

Comment: @KhalidShaukat Sorry, I don't seem to understand you very well, but could you EDit the answer to include the whole HTML code of the items and the images so I could help you?